# Find the supremum and the infimum of the following set o real numbers

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

> Let $A = \left\{ \dfrac{(n+m)^2}{2^{nm}} : n,m \in \mathbb{N} \right\}
>  $. Find $\sup A $ and $\inf A$

### Attempt:

My idea is to write $A_m = \left\{ \dfrac{(n+m)^2}{2^{nm}} : n\in \mathbb{N} \right\} $ and so $A = \bigcup_{m \geq 1} A_m $ So to find the sup, we know that $\sup A = \max_{m} (\sup A_m) $

So, we see that for $A_1 $, $\sup A_1 = 9/4$, and for $A_2$, $\sup A_2 = 9/4$, and $\sup A_3 = 2$ and eventually $\sup A_k = \dfrac{(n+k)^2 }{(2^k)^n } $ so clearly as $k$ gets bigger, $\sup A_k$ get smaller. Thus, $\max_m ( \sup A_m ) = \dfrac{9}{4} $ which implies that $\boxed{ \sup A = \dfrac{9}{4} }$

Finally, as for the infimum, we can observe that $\dfrac{(n+m)^2 }{2^{nm}} \geq 0$ for any $n,m$ and thus $\boxed{ \inf A = 0}$

Is my work correct?

Comment: Q1: Why does $\sup A_k$ depend on some variable other than $k$? Q2: Why does $\inf A\geqslant0$ dictate that $\inf A=0$?

Comment: To expand on Saad's points, $n$ is a dummy variable in the definition of $A_k$. I.e., it is a placeholder for the sake of the notation, and has no definition outside of that notation. But when you talk about $\sup A_k$, that is outside the scope of $n$'s definition, so $n$ is undefined at that point. Yet you would have $\sup A_k$ depend on this undefined value. For the other, You have shown enough to say that $\inf A \ge 0$. But you have nothing that indicates it is actually $= 0$.

Comment: A suggestion: write $\sup_{m}(\sup{}A_m)$ instead of $\max_{m}(\sup{}A_m)$, it is technically more correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea for your first part will work, but as was noted in the comments your statement that $\sup A_k=\frac{(n+k)^2}{(2^k)^n}$ really doesn’t make sense: $n$ is completely undefined here. You also need to fill in more details to justify some of your steps. After you’ve defined

$$A_m=\left\{\dfrac{(n+m)^2}{2^{nm}}:n\in\Bbb Z^+\right\}\;,$$

let $f_m(x)=\frac{(x+m)^2}{2^{mx}}$; then

$$\begin{align*}
f_m'(x)&=2(x+m)2^{-mx}-(x+m)^22^{-mx}\ln2\\
&=2^{-mx}(x+m)\big(2-(x+m)\ln2\big)\;,
\end{align*}$$

so $f_m(x)$ is increasing for for $x<\frac2{\ln 2}-m$ and decreasing for $x>\frac2{\ln 2}-m$. In particular, $\max A_1=f_1(2)=\frac94$, and $\max A_m=f_m(1)=\frac{(m+1)^2}{2^m}$ for $m>1$. A similar analysis shows that this attains its maximum at $m=2$, and $f_2(1)=\frac94$, so

$$\max\{\max A_m:m\in\Bbb Z^+\}=\frac94\;.$$

In other words, $\sup A=\frac94$ and is attained both at $m=1,n=2$ and at $m=2,n=1$, so that we can legitmately write $\max A=\frac94$.

As **Paul Sinclair** noted in the comments, you have only half of the argument needed to show that $\inf A=0$. Specifically, you’ve shown that $0$ is a lower bound for $A$, so clearly $0\le\inf A$. To finish the job you need to show that for each $\epsilon>0$ there are $m,n\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that $\frac{(n+m)^2}{2^{nm}}<\epsilon$. How fussily careful you have to be depends on how what has already been proved and can be taken for granted; I suspect that in your context it would suffice to take $m=1$ and note that $\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}\frac{(n+1)^2}{2^n}=0$.

Finally, in general it really is better to use $\sup$ when there is any possible question whether the supremum is attained, and I could well have used it throughout the first part of my answer. In this case I thought it sufficiently clear that I *was* producing actual maxima, so I went ahead and used $\max$.

Comment: Thank you very much prof Scott. I have a question: What if we havent yet defined $\lim$? How can we prove that $\inf A = 0 $ ?

Comment: @James: You’re welcome. Let $\epsilon>0$. There is an $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that $\frac1n<\frac{\epsilon}2$. Then $\frac2n<\epsilon$, and $\frac2n\in A$, so $\inf A\le 0$, and of course we have $\inf A\ge 0$ already.