# Maximal chain of a partially ordered set

Tags: set-theory

I've been studying set theory for 4 months but had a 3 months break and totally forgot how to do the following simple (?) exercise. Given a partially ordered set $P$ and the set $T$ of its chains (totally ordered subsets). Then we construct the set $C$ of cardinalities of $T$'s elements. $C$ must be well ordered by the inclusion. But how can we prove (if we can) $C$ contains maximal element? Can we apply Zorn's lemma here? Searched the answer here (the question concerns the Krull's dimension) but couldn't find. The answers are usually about concrete cases but not general. Will be glad if you'll give a hint or a link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s false. Consider the partial order $P$ that is the disjoint union of the cardinals $\omega_n$ for $n\in\omega$, each with its usual order. Formally $P=\bigcup_{n\in\omega}(\{n\}\times\omega_n)$ with the partial order $\preceq$ defined by

$$\langle m,\alpha\rangle\preceq\langle n,\beta\rangle\text{ iff }m=n\text{ and }\alpha\le\beta\;.$$

The individual cardinals are the maximal chains, and $C$ is the set of cardinals less than $\omega_\omega$, which has no maximum element: its supremum is $\omega_\omega$, which is not in the set.

Comment: Thank Prof. Scott. Prof can you help me with this? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3639519/find-the-supremum-and-the-infimum-of-the-following-set-o-real-numbers

Comment: @Brian M. Scott thanks for the nice example (I had to find it myself but forgot that if the maximal element exists it has to be the supremum).

Comment: @ElmarGuseinov: You’re welcome.